# How to check if item of string array can be converted to valid number?

Tags: javascript

I have a string arrays like `['2022/10', '2021/05', '2022/01']`, `['John','Olivia','Adam']`, `['1.23','2.34','101']` in the same table. I want to convert those items of arrays to number **but only if the item can be converted to number**. For above example only `['1.23','2.34','101']` can be converted and other should be same. I tried to combine common methods like `isNaN` and `parseFloat`
but couldn't manage. Because when I try to convert, it always gives **NaN** if the array can' be converted

Comment: Are you checking if all of the array members are numbers or just filter out the array members that are not number ?

Comment: If you had ['John','Olivia','Adam', '1'], should it return ['1']?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet does what you want to, or it will lead you towards the solution.

```js
const input = [['2022/10', '2021/05', '2022/01'], ['John','Olivia','Adam'], ['1.23','2.34','101']]

const converted = input.map(array => 
  isNaN(array[0]) ? array : array.map(number => parseFloat(number))
)

console.log(converted)
```

Alternatively, you can make it more general, so every term will get turned into a number even in array like `['John','2.4','2022/10']`:

```js
const input = [['2022/10', '2021/05', '2022/01'], ['John','Olivia','Adam'], ['1.23','2.34','101']]

const converted = input.map(array => 
  array.map(
    numberOrNotNumber => isNaN(numberOrNotNumber) ? numberOrNotNumber : parseFloat(numberOrNotNumber)
  )
)

console.log(converted)
```